# Создать свой курсор в Jetpack Compose Desktop

Tags: kotlin, compose-desktop

Как создать свой курсор на компонент в Jetpack Compose Desktop.

```
Text(text = "Белово",
    modifier = Modifier
        .pointerHoverIcon(icon = PointerIcon.Hand, overrideDescendants = true)
    )
```

В таком варианте всего четыре курсора